# ExtJS - set panel in Div to 100%

Tags: html, extjs, width

There is 1 Div-container, into which I want to render my full application. The application shall fill out the whole Div width.

I have tried both the following Divs, but still the Div-container is not 100%, there is even no width like as if there is no content. What is wrong?

```
<div id="stuff"></div>
```

and

```
<div style="width: 100%;" id="stuff"></div>
```

My ExtJS app:

```
                    launch: function() {

                    var div = Ext.Element.get('stuff');

                    Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
                        renderTo: div,
                        width: "100%",
                        height: 500,
                        title: 'Container Panel',
                        layout: 'border',
                        items: [
                            {
                                xtype: 'panel',
                                title: 'Child Panel 1',
                                height: '80%',
                                width: '100%'
                            },
                            {
                                xtype: 'panel',
                                title: 'Child Panel 2',
                                html: 'textextetxtext',
                                height: '80%',
                                width: '100%'
                            }
                        ]
                    });
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help. There were several additional Divs of the framework on top. So removing them solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the div to a fixed width in pixels instead of just 100%. In other words, if I give you 100% of my money, and you get nothing, it's because I have no money. Similarly, you have 100% width specified, but of what? Perhaps the #stuff div needs a containing div to draw its 100% width from.

Furthermore, both child panels Have 100% width and 80% height. Try 50% each.